# How do I locate my staticwebapp.config.json in Azure Devops release Deploy Azure Static Web App?

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-static-web-app, azure-static-web-app-routing

I have a pipeline that builds the artificat for my **Angular** app. Deployment works fine until I try to go to specific URLs. It redirects me to 404. This has to do with the `staticwebapp.config.json`. It looks like:

```
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html",
    "exclude": ["*.{css,scss,js,png,gif,ico,jpg,svg}"]
  }
}
```

I have a created a release pipeline in Azure Devops to release it to my **Static Web App** on Azure. This is how my `.yaml` looks like:

```
steps:
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  displayName: 'Static Web App: '
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/xx/xx/xx-xx-web'
    app_location: /
    output_location: dist
    config_file_location: configuration
    skip_app_build: true
    skip_api_build: true
    is_static_export: false
    verbose: true
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: 'SOMEVALUE'
```

The staticwebapp.config.json is located here:

- src

  - app
  - assets
  - configuration

    - **staticwebapp.config.json**

This is the error I get during the release:

```
##[error]routes_location: route file 'staticwebapp.config.json/routes.json' could not be found.
```

or when I fill in the `config_file_location`:

```
##[error]config_file_location: config file '/configuration/staticwebapp.config.json' could not be found.
```

How do I locate the file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem is solved. I did the following:

The `staticwebapp.config.json` file should be in the built artifact that comes out of the build pipeline. And this file was nowhere to be found. What I did, was putting the config file in the `assets` folder, because this folder is completely being taken over during the build. This piece of configuration in the `angular.json` file in your solution takes care of that:

```
"assets": [
 "src/favicon.ico",
 "src/assets"
]
```

It takes over everything inside the assets folder. You can also put the exact location in this assets array, but I kept it simple. After a new build, I saw the `staticwebapp.config.json` appearing in the built artifact in the `assets` folder.

My `.yaml` for deploying it to **Azure Static Web App** now looks like this below:

```
steps:
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  displayName: 'Static Web App: '
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/xx/xx/xx-xx-web'
    app_location: /
    output_location: dist
    config_file_location: /assets
    skip_app_build: true
    skip_api_build: true
    is_static_export: false
    verbose: true
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: 'SOMEVALUE'
```

Comment: This was helpful, I did not have to set a `config_file_location` doing so resulted in "config_file_location: config file '/assets/staticwebapp.config.json' could not be found."

I did elect to add `src/azure` to the angular.json assets which was a good place to organize the `staticwebapp.config.json` and associated `environment.yml` files

Comment: As @TylerV mentioned i had got an error and had to mention ```config_file_location: src/assets```

Answer (score 1):

If you define the working directory as '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/xx/xx/xx-xx-web' in task: AzureStaticWebApp@0. Then it will try to locate your staticwebapp.config.json in this directory.

I have modified your script. You could have a test.

```
steps:
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  displayName: 'Static Web App: '
  inputs:
    app_location: /
    output_location: 'dist'
    config_file_location: '/src'
    skip_app_build: true
    skip_api_build: true
    is_static_export: false
    verbose: true
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: 'SOMEVALUE'
```

Check this link for the arguments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/azure-static-web-app?view=azure-devops#arguments

[image]

Comment: It didn't work, same error. It can't find the json file. I was looking in my working directory and the artifact that the build has produced, I also don't see any staticwebapp.config.json file inside. Is that right?

Comment: Fixed, answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to add the `staticwebapp.config.json` anywhere you like within the project folder, and then modify the `angular.json` file by adding a new entry in the `assets` section. Here's how mine looks like:

```
"assets": [
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/assets",
      "src/staticwebapp.config.json"
    ],
```